# Roslyn analyzer - resolving base classes deep does not work during editing

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

We have some custom roslyn analyzers for one of our .net project. Some of the rules need to analyze all base classes deep of a given `ClassDeclaration`. The problem is, that we also need the `SematicModel` which belongs to the base classes in order to resolve the `GetDeclaredSymbol` of that `ClassDeclaration`. Currently we are getting the `SemanticModel` by resolving it at the `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext.Compilation`.

This works when compiling our project from the scratch, but when editing the code roslyn analyzers are also executed periodically.
*Sometimes we are getting a System.ArgumentException mentioning the SyntaxTree is not part of the compilation.*
Is there a save way to analyze all base classes of a given ClassDeclaration with the need to have the `SemanticModel` belonging to each base class as well as the SyntaxNode which is currently analysed. Please find the code below which shows how we are analyzing the base class currently.

**Does anybody has an idea how to avoid the error mentioned above or what I am doing wrong?**

```cs
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterCompilationStartAction(compilationContext =>
    {
        //... here we are collecting some base stuff from the compilationContext.Compilation
        compilationContext.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(syntaxNodeAnalysisContext => 
        {
           var classDeclaration = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)syntaxNodeAnalysisContext.Node;
           var meAndBaseClasses = GetClassDeclarationsDeep(classDeclaration, compilationContext.Compilation);
           // now we can analyze the current node because we have infos about all bases classes deep
        }, SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration);
    });
}

protected IEnumerable<ClassDeclarationSyntax> GetClassDeclarationsDeep(ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration, Compilation compilation)
{
    foreach (var type in classDeclaration.GetMeAndBaseTypes(compilation.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.SyntaxTree)))
    {
        foreach (var partialType in GetClassDeclarations(type, compilation))
        {
            yield return partialType;
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetMeAndBaseTypes(this ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration, SemanticModel semanticModel)
{
    return GetMeAndBaseTypes(semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration));
}

protected IEnumerable<ClassDeclarationSyntax> GetClassDeclarations(INamedTypeSymbol classType, Compilation compilation)
{
    return classType.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.SelectMany(t => t.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()).Where(t => SymbolEqualityComparer.Equals(classType, compilation.GetSemanticModel(t.SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(t)));
}

public static IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetMeAndBaseTypes(this INamedTypeSymbol type)
{
    List<INamedTypeSymbol> types = new List<INamedTypeSymbol>();
    while (type != null)
    {
        types.Add(type);
        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    return types;
}
```

Comment: What is "syntaxNodeContext"? I don't see that defined in your snippet -- I suspect in editing down something got mis-edited?

Comment: That was a typo, I have fixed it above.